# Trying to capture the Error message in user variable "User::ErrorMsg" in SSIS and also add the variable in Event Handler mail task

Tags: ssis

I am using this user variable "User::ErrorMsg" in the Eventhandler mail task.

But the value is always null.

```
   catch (Exception ExMsg)
        {
            string ErrorMsg = null;
            ErrorMsg = ExMsg.GetType().FullName + "<br>" +
               ExMsg.Message + "<br>" + ExMsg.StackTrace;

            Dts.Variables["User::ErrorMsg"].Value = ErrorMsg.ToString();

            throw;

        }
```

Comment: Instead of throwing the error return a success from the script task.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `throw;` at the end of your `catch` block, use:

```
Dts.TaskResult = (int)DTSExecResult.Failure;
```

Likewise, when your script finishes with no error, use:

```
Dts.TaskResult = (int)DTSExecResult.Success;
```